# YouTube Data API playlistItems:List only returns max of 100 data items - or 2 pages of data, was working normally July 16

Tags: api, youtube

I am using YouTube Data API v3 - and today playlistItems:List only returns max of 100 data items or 2 pages of data for the all videos playlist (UU + last 22 char of channel id) . I believe the next page token also may be incorrect after the first page, because it shows the wrong previous page token on the third page.

```
UPDATE: Further testing shows that the playlistItems:List api works correctly 
for some channels -

All video playlist - UU4mLlRa_dezwvytudo9s1sw works

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UU4mLlRa_dezwvytudo9s1sw%22%7D


but at least two others do not work correctly and only return 100 items:

UUGGZ_POGmIWG1pQXTDzQv-g
UUwD4x63A9KC7Si2RuSfg-SA
```

This has been working correctly for several years. It worked correctly July 16. The same behavior happens in the API Explorer.

API Explorer example & results for all video playlist UUwD4x63A9KC7Si2RuSfg-SA:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22pageToken%22%3A%22CDIQAA%22%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUwD4x63A9KC7Si2RuSfg-SA%22%7D`

```
first page of results:

{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "oE9yCl2NBCpgzQbX82RR1jjqkco",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "items": [


second page - page token CDIQAA:

{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "w8PJ0yDadTWJfwSP2CWcODoMzuk",
  "nextPageToken": "CGQQAA",
  "prevPageToken": "CDIQAQ",
  "items": [

third page - page token CGQQAA:

{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "AQSyYYKWgu50RiGPA10TjRTE7Ys",
  "nextPageToken": "CJYBEAA",
  "prevPageToken": "CGQQAQ",    
  "items": [],                  <---- NO DATA, but 521 items still to show
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 621,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  }
}
```

POSSIBLE WORKAROUNDS

1. Use YouTube Data API v3 - search:List specifying channel ID, no query, and result filter type = videos. This is expensive in quota, it costs 100 quota per query/page of 50 results. However, this API now seems to max out at about 300 or so results for a channel.
2. Use YouTube Data API v3 - playlistItems:List with a channel-owner authorized OAuth token instead of the public API key. This works as before without the 100 item limit. However, it means you cannot get a video list (over 100 videos) for a channel or a playlist without an OAuth token from the owner.

Comment: Found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161399038 which appears to be the YouTube API's issue tracker reporting the same issue.

Comment: supposedly fixed now https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161628022 and looking ok in my limited testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the YouTube API. Public acknowledgement and tracking of the bug is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161628022

#### EDIT: appears to be fixed as of 2020-07-24

There are some duplicates, too. I found

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147096849
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161399038

Probably best to just wait for it to be fixed. It has only been open/assigned for a day or so, so it might get fixed quickly. Then again, it might not. It has happened before and taken a long time to fix.

Heuristically, it looks to me like this is a limitation on Unlisted Playlists, which is to say Playlists not returned by `playlists.list` given the `channelId`.

I checked and confirmed that even when using smaller page sizes, only the first 100 playlist items are returned for unlisted playlists (I only looked at "uploads" playlists as I do not have a lot of big unlisted playlists handy), and using page size of 50, listed playlists will return all the items (playlist `PLC474234E124B5213` returns all 102 items, playlist `FLSC1HqVmTaE4Shn32ihbC7w` returns all 136 items). In my experience, there are rarely workarounds for these kinds of bugs in the YouTube API. It is not worth spending a lot of time on. Live with the limit for now, document (to whoever cares) that it is a known bug/limitation, and move on as if it is a documented limitation with a pending feature request to remove the limitation.