# Youtube API v3 PlaylistItem return only first 100 items of playlist since 18.07.20 for some channels

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

I am working on a web-app which use Youtube API for marketing research and recently we stuck a strange change in Youtube API work.
I am getting a channel videos with the help of code which was getting videos from channel upload playlist.  I take a channelId, transform it to this channel upload playlist playlistID and with youtube youtube-api v3 playlistItem method list videos from it, page by page(50 results per page).

And previously there was no problems with it. But recently, around 18.07.20, for some channels this method have stopped to work properly.
If previously I could get this way thousand or even more videos, now some channels are limited to barely 100 videos or 2 pages. And there is no changes in Youtube API documentation or in revision history regarding this.

For example, here is example of such behavior.
Example Channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/WWEFanNation
Channels video count: 48,582
Channels ID: UCJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg
Channels upload playlistId: UUJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg

First request:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg%22%7D

Code 200, results items 50

Second request:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22pageToken%22%3A%22CDIQAA%22%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg%22%7D

Code 200, results items 50

Third request:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22pageToken%22%3A%22CGQQAA%22%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg%22%7D

Code 200, results items 0. Page don`t have results, but have a nextPageToken. All next pages, at least 20, are empty.

And this happening with pretty much 50% of channels. Some channels can give back full list of 400 videos+, other give back only part of videos or limited by 100 results.

I have tried in meantime to use https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list for channelId, but it give back not all videos, but most relevant. And can miss alot of videos because of it.

This especially frustrating because there was no changes in documentation, so it is absolutely unclear why some channels are caped, while other are not.

So questions is:

1. Does anybody know what is happening?
2. Is there another way to consistently get all videos for channel sorted by upload date?

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963399/youtube-data-api-playlistitemslist-only-returns-max-of-100-data-items-or-2-pa which has a link to google's bug tracker about the problem.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161628022 says this is fixed now. it is looking good in my testing so far.