# Youtube Data API - PlaylistItems: list returns max of 20,000 videos when called using API key, returns full video list when using OAuth token

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

`PlaylistItems: list` returns max of 20,000 videos when called using API key, while returning full video list when using OAuth token.

Example: `UCj1J3QuIftjOq9iv_rr7Egw` -- use *uploads* playlist ID `UUj1J3QuIftjOq9iv_rr7Egw`: using an API key returns 20,000 videos; using OAuth token returns 34897 videos.

This is similar to [previous SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963399) --- [recorded as a Google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161628022) too.

Comment: What is your question, please? The [magic value 20000](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166292064#comment2) is a known limit of the API. The difference between using an API key and an access token (obtained via an OAuth 2.0 flow) is the following: using the former allows one to only read public data associated to any YouTube channel; the latter allows one the read and write any data that belongs the authorized YouTube channel (modulo the scopes attached during the OAuth flow).

Comment: I have been using this API for 5 years, and have never encountered a limit using the API key. I performed this same query on the same channel in 05/2020 and had no limits, received 31000 videos data then. Also, unless there was a very recent change, there is no limit in the docs.

Comment: By the way, did you actually paginated the whole set of 34897 videos of `UUj1J3QuIftjOq9iv_rr7Egw`? Or else that number was given to you by the playlist's property [`itemCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#contentDetails.itemCount) or by channel's property [`videoCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.videoCount)? (Querying those two properties myself, I've got 20000 and 32592 respectively.)

Comment: Actual download of 600+ pages

Comment: Indeed, *the by design change* is quite recent. You'll never find limits specified by the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/). This is unfortunate, but a fact.

Comment: You might be interesting by a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69121286/7123660) I coded to fake a manual web browse of the "Videos" tab of a given YouTube channel.